# Multiple processes sharing / reading from one large block of CUDA device memory

Tags: cuda, mpi, ipc, multiprocess

I have a multi-process application with a single GPU using CUDA multi process service (MPS). Each process creates several device arrays, however one of them is large (~5 GB), and its a constant array, so I thought I could allocate the memory once with one process, and instruct other processes to read from that memory block using "inter process communication" (similar to the CUDA API example shown [here](https://github.com/ndd314/cuda_examples/blob/master/0_Simple/simpleIPC/simpleIPC.cu) ).

Following the linked CUDA example, I tried to implement a simple test program, but have been hitting an API error. It seems when I call [`cudaIPCOpenMemHandle`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g01050a29fefde385b1042081ada4cde9), I have an invalid argument. I post the code below, in hopes that someone might easily identify the reason for the error, or perhaps suggest a better use of the CUDA API to accomplish what Im trying to do.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define blockSize 128
#define N 1000
#define gpuErr(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }


__global__ void kernel(double* out, double* in, double val){
    unsigned int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int thread_stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i=tid; i < N; i+=thread_stride){
        out[i] = in[i]*val;
    }
}

static void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

static void error_msg(cudaError_t err, int rank){
    if (err != cudaSuccess){
        printf("RANK %d recvd CUDA error message: %s\n", rank, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(err);
    }
}

void check_access(){
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    gpuErr(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0));
    if (prop.unifiedAddressing)
        printf("> GPU%d = is capable of UVA\n", 0);

    // NOTE: only interested in enabling intra-device peer2peer, so I think this test doesnt matter ?
    //int can_access=-1;
    //int num_dev=2;
    //// note, here I was confused, I want the ability to have a process on device 0 access
    //for (peer_dev=0; peer_dev <num_dev, peer_dev++){
    //    int peer_dev=0; // note if peer_dev is 1
    //    gpuErr(cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer(&can_access, 0,peer_dev));
    //    if (can_access)
    //        printf("device 0 has peerdev=%d access\n", peer_dev);
    //    else
    //        printf("device 0 has no peerdev=%d access\n", peer_dev);
    //}
}

int main(){
    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    int size,rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank==0)
        check_access();
    gpuErr(cudaSetDevice(0));

    double* out;
    double * in;
    gpuErr(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&out, N*sizeof(double)));

    cudaIpcMemHandle_t * memHand = (cudaIpcMemHandle_t *)
        mmap(NULL, sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t),
            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);

    assert(MAP_FAILED != memHand);
    memset((void *) memHand, 0, sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t));

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank==0){
        gpuErr(cudaMalloc((void **)&in, N*sizeof(double)));
        gpuErr(cudaIpcGetMemHandle((cudaIpcMemHandle_t *) &memHand[0], (void *)in));
        
        double * temp = new double[N];
        for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
            temp[i] = 1;
        gpuErr(cudaMemcpy(in, temp, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        delete temp;
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // the following is throwing a CUDAerror, invalid
    if (rank >0 )
        gpuErr(cudaIpcOpenMemHandle((void **) &in, memHand[0], cudaIpcMemLazyEnablePeerAccess));
    
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    double rank_val=(double) rank;
    kernel<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(out, in, rank_val);
    error_msg(cudaGetLastError(), rank);
    gpuErr(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // test the kernel results
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
        sum += out[i];
    printf("mpirank=%d, comm.size=%d, result=%f\n", rank, size, sum);
    assert(sum==N*rank);

    // cleanup
    if (rank>0)
        cudaIpcCloseMemHandle(in);
    cudaFree(out);
    if (rank==0)
        cudaFree(in);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with

```
 nvcc -I/usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/include  --compiler-options=-march=skylake-avx512 -L/usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib -lmpi ipc_tester.cu
```

Single process job output: (looks correct)

```
$ srun -n1 -c2 ./a.out
> GPU0 = is capable of UVA
mpirank=0, comm.size=1, result=0.000000
```

Multi process job output: (hits error in call `cudaIPCOpenMemHandle`)

```
$ srun -n2 -c2 ./a.out
GPUassert: invalid argument ipc_tester.cu 92
```

Compute sanitizer output:

```
$ srun -n2 -c2 compute-sanitizer ./a.out
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x15553e03f170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x15553e6c44c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e9095a9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90a7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90abfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15553e90b7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x155546040170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x15553edc7e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x1555466c54c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690a5a9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690b7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690bbfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15554690c7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x155546dc8e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x15553e03f170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x15553e6c44c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e9095a9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90a7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90abfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15553e90b7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x15553edc7e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x155546040170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x1555466c54c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690a5a9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690b7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690bbfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15554690c7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x155546dc8e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
========= Program hit invalid device context (error 201) on CUDA API call to cuCtxGetDevice.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:cuCtxGetDevice [0x155550d083eb]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x15553e03f170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:uct_cuda_base_query_devices [0x155546040170]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/ucx/libuct_cuda.so.0
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x15553e6c44c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e9095a9]
=========     Host Frame:uct_md_query_tl_resources [0x1555466c54c6]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libuct.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690a5a9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690b7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15554690bbfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90a7f9]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame: [0x15553e90abfd]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15553e90b7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:ucp_init_version [0x15554690c7f3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/ucx/1.10.1/lib/libucp.so.0
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x155546dc8e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========     Host Frame:mca_pml_ucx_open [0x15553edc7e70]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/openmpi/mca_pml_ucx.so
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_components_open [0x15555299ef2d]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x155554472ec7]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:mca_base_framework_open [0x1555529a8b31]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libopen-pal.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:ompi_mpi_init [0x15555447fb5b]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========     Host Frame:MPI_Init [0x15555442dc01]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/openmpi/4.0.3/gcc/lib/libmpi.so.40
=========     Host Frame: [0x403f04]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
========= Program hit invalid argument (error 1) on CUDA API call to cudaIpcOpenMemHandle.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame: [0x155550dde1b3]
=========                in /usr/common/software/sles15_cgpu/cuda/11.1.1/lib64/compat/libcuda.so.1
=========     Host Frame: [0x433fac]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame: [0x40412e]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
=========     Host Frame:__libc_start_main [0x1555531173ea]
=========                in /lib64/libc.so.6
=========     Host Frame: [0x403d1a]
=========                in /global/cfs/cdirs/lcls/dermen/dulios/./a.out
========= 
GPUassert: invalid argument ipc_tester.cu 92
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Target application returned an error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors
```

System info:

```
$ lsb_release  -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2
Release:        15.2
Codename:       n/a

$ nvidia-smi 
Tue Sep 27 10:05:48 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.102.04   Driver Version: 450.102.04   CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:89:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P0    38W / 300W |      0MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: you have to communicate the handle from one process to another.  For all your ranks other than 0, they are trying to use the `memHand[0]` that was initialized to zero via `memset` and *never set to anything else*.  That is why you are getting invalid argument.  `memHand[0]` of all zeros is not a valid handle.  The CUDA IPC sample code demonstrates the passing of handles via  a host IPC mechanism.  You should be able to use a MPI broadcast mechanism to send the handle from rank 0 to the other ranks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871402/multiple-processes-sharing-reading-from-one-large-block-of-cuda-device-memory#comment130438226_73871402), the memHandler was not properly set on ranks>0.

After learning how to [broadcast the memHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872764/broadcasting-structs-without-knowing-attributes), I arrived at a solution. The patch below leads to a working code.

```
@@ -66,12 +66,7 @@ int main(){
     double * in;
     gpuErr(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&out, N*sizeof(double)));
 
-    cudaIpcMemHandle_t * memHand = (cudaIpcMemHandle_t *)
-        mmap(NULL, sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t),
-            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
-
-    assert(MAP_FAILED != memHand);
-    memset((void *) memHand, 0, sizeof(cudaIpcMemHandle_t));
+    cudaIpcMemHandle_t memHand[1];
 
     MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 
@@ -87,6 +82,21 @@ int main(){
     }
     MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 
+//  Broadcast the MPI handle
+//  get size of memHandler container needed for broadcast
+    int hand_size[1];
+    if (rank==0)
+        hand_size[0]= sizeof(memHand[0]);
+    MPI_Bcast(&hand_size[0], 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
+
+    // create the char container for memHandler broadcast
+    char memHand_C[hand_size[0]];
+    if (rank==0)
+        memcpy(&memHand_C, &memHand[0], hand_size[0]);
+    MPI_Bcast(&memHand_C, hand_size[0], MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
+    if (rank >0)
+        memcpy(&memHand[0], &memHand_C, hand_size[0]);
+
     // the following is throwing a CUDAerror, invalid
     if (rank >0 )
         gpuErr(cudaIpcOpenMemHandle((void **) &in, memHand[0], cudaIpcMemLazyEnablePeerAccess));
```